# ngClick toggle class is impacting all elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a group of elements that when one is clicked that one should toggle a class. The problem I have is that when one of the elements is clicked, all of the elements receive the toggled class.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" class="editor-row">

<div flex="initial">
    <div class="gradient-btn" ng-click="toggle.state = !toggle.state" ng-class="{'focus' : toggle.state}">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data.fontStyle.bold" aria-label="Bold" entersubmit="ok()">Bold</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>

<div flex="initial">
    <div class="gradient-btn" ng-click="toggle.state = !toggle.state" ng-class="{'focus' : toggle.state}">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data.fontStyle.italic" aria-label="Italic" entersubmit="ok()">Italic</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>

<div flex="initial">
    <div class="gradient-btn" ng-click="toggle.state = !toggle.state" ng-class="{'focus' : toggle.state}">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data.fontStyle.shadow" aria-label="Shadow" entersubmit="ok()">Shadow</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all in the same scope, hence `toggle.state` variable is the same.

change to: toggleBold.state, toggleItalic.state, ...

Answer (score 1):

All of the elements refer to the same toggle.state

When you click on the first one, toggle.state variable change and all of the elements having `ng-class="{'focus' : toggle.state}"` are impacted.